# Rename files based on word count

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename, batch-rename

Would it be possible to rename a bunch of files in a directory based on their word counts such as below:

For all the files in `folderA`, get their word count and then rename them based on their word count

So `AMS_01_ex345_2012040000000_0001235.NEW`, the word count for this file is *1234* and it would be renamed to `AMS_01_ex345_2012040000000_0001234.NEW`

`for x in $folder1 do exec grep -v "\"" $x | 'wc -l' > "$x.NEW"`

Comment: So you want to replace the last part of filename (between `_` and `.NEW`) with the correct word count? Or only append the number to the filename?

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to replace the last parts between _ and .NEW with the word count

Answer (score 2):

```
for f in $folder1/*; do
  cnt=$(wc -l $f)
  printf -v num "%07u" ${cnt% *}
  mv $f ${f%_*}_$num.NEW
done
```

(For testing you can put `echo` before the `mv`, so that no destruction will occur.)

First, we assign the output of `wc` command into variable `$cnt` (for example `567 AMS_01_ex345_2012040000000_0001235.NEW`). Then we need to get only the number out of it and format this number with leading zeros. `printf -v num` assigns the result into that variable.

`${parameter%word}` in bash will remove matching suffix pattern. In our first case we will remove from `$cnt` the last space and everything after it. In our second case, will remove from `$f` the last underscore and everything after it.

**EDIT:** This counts the lines, not words. I was confused by usage of `wc -l` in the question itself. To count words, use `wc -w`.